Pseudosphere construction- inaccuracy
In the following a construction of a right triangle on a pseudosphere is attempted on Mathematica, given the following input for triangle construction.
$$ \text{side} ~a =1.0, C= \pi/2, A=\pi/3, \text{triangle area} = 0.16029956716889648` $$
Triangle area is also given to determine the size of the right triangle set to result in a unit pseudoradius $a$.
Sides CA,CB are geodesic sides of a right triangle, AB is the hypotenuse. Sides of triangle are computed using the Law of Sine/Sinh s. Differentials of the Clairaut's law and constant negative  principal Gauss curvature product $ K=-1/a^2 $ are coded in NDSolve. Arcs (b,c) start and end on the equator line $a=BC$, vertex A lying on the smaller parallel circle.
Clear["Global`*"];
" To compute and Show a Hyperbolic geometry Right Trianmgle "
thC = Pi/2.; A = Pi/6; a = 1.0;
Eq = {Sinh[c] == Sinh[a] Sin[thC]/Sin[A], Cosh[b] == Cosh[c]/Cosh[a], 
   Sin[B] == Sin[A] Sinh[b] Sinh[a]};
NSolve[Eq, {c, b, B}]
B = 0.8868979840277016`
c = 1.5901921366012282`
b = 1.0900549655347782`
PSDefect = Pi - (A + B + thC)
PSarea = 0.16029956716889648`
aaPS = Sqrt[PSarea/PSDefect]
aaPSabove
"START SIDE ONE"
a = 1.; thi = 0; zi = 0.;
phi = -Pi/2 + 10^-7;
sii = 0.
ri = a  ; smax = b;
" C to A geodesic hypotenuse"
PSmuLT1 = {SI'[s] == -Sin[PH[s]] Sin[SI[s]]/R[s], SI[0] == sii, 
   Cos[PH[s]] PH'[s]/(R[s] Cos[SI[s]]) == 1/a^2, PH[0] == phi, 
   R'[s] == Sin[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]], Z'[s] == Cos[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]], 
   TH'[s] == Sin[SI[s]]/R[s], R[0] == ri, Z[0] == zi, TH[0] == 0.};
NDSolve[PSmuLT1, {SI, PH, R, TH, Z}, {s, 0, smax}];
{si[t_], ph[t_], r[t_], th[t_], 
   z[t_]} = {SI[t], PH[t], R[t], TH[t], Z[t]} /. First[%];
mer1 = ParametricPlot[{z[s], r[s]}, {s, .0, smax}, PlotLabel -> MERDN,
    GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}];
Plot[ -Sin[ph[s]]^2 + r[s]^2/a^2, {s, .0, smax}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> PS merdn chk]
pp1 = ParametricPlot[{r[s] Cos[th[s]], r[s] Sin[th[s]]}, {s, .0, 
    smax}, PlotLabel -> PolarPlot, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Magenta}];
sor1 = ParametricPlot3D[{r[s] Cos[th[s] + v], r[s] Sin[th[s] + v], 
    z[s]}, {s, .0, smax}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity[0.1]}];
fila1 = ParametricPlot3D[{r[s] Cos[th[s]], r[s] Sin[th[s]], 
    z[s]}, {s, .0, smax}, PlotLabel -> 3 _D Projn, 
   PlotStyle -> {Green, Thick}];
s1 = Show[{sor1, fila1}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> Automatic, 
  Boxed -> False, PlotLabel -> "PS_HYP_TRIA"]
"r-th-zz-ph-si before A "
riA = r[smax]
thiA = th[smax]
ziA = z[smax]
phiA = ph[smax]
siA = si[smax]
end of side one
start of side two
" si A after A "
siiA = siA + Pi/6 + Pi
"NOTE angle  A CHANGED "
" A to B  geodesic arc"
smax = c; (* cut short by singularity !! *)
smax = 1.152250667996393` ;
part2 = {SI'[s] == -Sin[PH[s]] Sin[SI[s]]/R[s], SI[0] == siiA, 
   Cos[PH[s]] PH'[s]/(R[s] Cos[SI[s]]) == 1/a^2, PH[0] == phiA,
   R'[s] == Sin[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]], Z'[s] == Cos[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]], 
   TH'[s] == Sin[SI[s]]/R[s], R[0] == riA, Z[0] == ziA, TH[0] == thiA};
NDSolve[part2, {SI, PH, R, TH, Z}, {s, 0, smax}];
{si[t_], ph[t_], r[t_], th[t_], 
   z[t_]} = {SI[t], PH[t], R[t], TH[t], Z[t]} /. First[%];
mer2 = ParametricPlot[{z[s], r[s]}, {s, .0, smax}, PlotLabel -> MERDN,
    GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}];
Plot[si''[s] - Sin[si[s]] Cos[si[s]]/a^2, {s, .0, smax}, 
 PlotLabel -> SineGordon]
Plot[ -Sin[ph[s]]^2 + r[s]^2/a^2, {s, .0, smax}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> PS merdn chk]
pp2 = ParametricPlot[{r[s] Cos[th[s]], r[s] Sin[th[s]]}, {s, .0, 
    smax}, PlotLabel -> PolarPlot, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Magenta}];
sor1 = ParametricPlot3D[{r[s] Cos[th[s] + v], r[s] Sin[th[s] + v], 
    z[s]}, {s, .0, smax}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> Geods on PS, 
   Mesh -> {6, 8}, PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity[0.1]}];
fila1 = ParametricPlot3D[{r[s] Cos[th[s]], r[s] Sin[th[s]], 
    z[s]}, {s, .0, smax}, PlotLabel -> 3 _D Projn, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];
s2 = Show[{sor1, fila1}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> Automatic, 
   Boxed -> False, PlotLabel -> "PS_HYP_TRIA"];
"s2 above"
Show[{s1, s2}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "TwoSegments", 
 AspectRatio -> 0.6, PlotLabel -> Meridians_BOTH _GOOF]
{r[smax], th[smax]*180./Pi, z[smax]}
Plot[si''[s] - Sin[si[s]] Cos[si[s]]/a^2, {s, .0, smax}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Sine-Gordon Relation Of Hyperbolic Chebychev Net even by a geodesic !!"]


Geodesic line BC is not drawn.
Carefully avoided errors, but some errors may still have crept in. Hope the image is reasonably satisfactory. However during construction three related issues remain:

The polar angle of point B calculates to $40.8144^{\circ}$ where as  $\approx 57.3^{\circ}$is expected as the arc BC and radius are 1.0 each.

The Sine-Gordon equation ( valid for asymptotic lines $(\kappa_n=0, K=-1/a^2)),$  however it is satisfied by geodesics on AB$ (\kappa_g=0 , K=-1/a^2).$  How can it even be true?
In fact the former is valid for different hyperbolic geodesics of the pseudosphere but still the justification does not add up. It is puzzling how it  could be true for this geodesic type as well.

The Sin/Sinh Rule calculates the hypotenuse length to be 1.590192136601282. However a singularity stops computation at a reduced length 1.152250667996393`. (encountering inverse circular trig function modulus > 1 etc). So the Sin/ Sinh Rule is really not respected..


Please comment on these aspects of the above construction or if there is a better way to calculate triangles on surfaces of negative curvature. Shall furnish any needed details /clarifications.  Thanks.
